# FCM NOTIFICATION ISSUE IN BACKGROUND

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating the FCM using AWS , but when my app is killed and notification come , i am unable to open my desired fragment . I am receiving the data payload from the FCM . The app is working fine when app is in foreground or background(i.e when user minimize the app). I spent a day and googled everything still i am unable to achieve it ,i figured that in activity file my new intent is not fired when app is killed and notification come and user tap into the notification , it's open default Activity but i want when user tap the notification the newIntent in activity is called and it's change my target fragment. Here is my code :

FCM RECIVER :

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
         if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            String  message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
             String  additionalData = remoteMessage.getData().get("additionalData");
             try {
                 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(additionalData);
                 orderId=Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("orderId"));
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             sendNotification(orderId, message);
         }
```

Here is sendNotication method :

```
private void sendNotification(Integer orderId,String message) {

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        //AppMethod.setIntegerPreference(getApplicationContext(),NOTIFICATION_ID,)
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putInt("order_id", orderId);
        intent.putExtras(mBundle);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        int dummyuniqueInt = new Random().nextInt(543254);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, dummyuniqueInt, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(orderId+"")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        //int notification_unique_id = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(dummyuniqueInt, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

Here is the Activity code to receive an intent ,the intent is not working when notification come when user tap it's opening my default fragment ,but i want newIntent should fire here and open my target fragemnet, when app is killed state.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bottomBar.setCurrentItem(0, false);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new CheckInFragment(), CheckInFragment.Fragment_TAG).commit();
        if(intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getExtras()!=null){
            hideKeyboard(this);
                meetingId =intent.getExtras().getInt("order_id");
            }
        setIntent(intent);
    }
```

Here is my data payload :

'GCM': {

```
'data': {
  'message': 'Receive my nottttitititiititititititiitititiitiitiitttttttttttt',
  'sound': 'default',
  'badge': 1,
   'priority': 'normal',
  'additionalData': {
    'orderId': 7,
  },
}
```

},

Comment: newintent called when there is old activity still exist. when app is killed no intent is exist

Comment: Thanks then how to achieve my target fragment

Comment: pass specific value to activity and inside activity check if value match then load fragment

Comment: i tried to recieve my bundle in oncreate of my activity that i had put in fcm receiver, but bundle comes null

Comment: Thanks I found the solution i have to add both newIntent aswell as this line to oncreate :  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); extras.getInt("order_id").,when app is in background i check oncreate of bundle and change the fragment and when app is in foreground it's check newIntent method from the activity and change the target fragment

Comment: Could you show the full solution? I made as you suggested, but extras.getInt("order_id") inside onCreate still 0. And what the version of com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging do you use?